# Mouseover instead of onclick (marker)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, mousehover

I want to display the infowindow with an onmouseover event instead of onclick event.

the problem is when I change my cursor location out of the marker, my infowindow disappear, while I have in my infowindow a link .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>multi-marqueurs</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 700px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var locations = [
     ['<span id="ss">Jérôme et Catherine Blondel</span>', 49.898729,3.13606, 5],
      ['Laurent et Sabine Blondel', 50.684142,3.1360678, 4],
      ['Noël et Anne Marie Blondel', 49.953802, 2.360237, 3],
      ['Jean Luc et Catherine Blondel<br /> <a href="http://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</a>', 48.606369,2.886894, 2]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.4,1.6),
          mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
     navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
        scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

   for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
    /*var pictureLabel = document.createElement("img");
     pictureLabel.src = "home.jpg";*/
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        /*title    : "CRIAQ",
        icon     : "disk.png"*/
      });


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.close(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }​
-->
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>multi-marqueurs</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height: 700px;"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var infowindow;
      function initialize() {

        var locations = [['<span id="ss">Jérôme et Catherine Blondel</span>', 49.898729, 3.13606, 5], ['Laurent et Sabine Blondel', 50.684142, 3.1360678, 4], ['Noël et Anne Marie Blondel', 49.953802, 2.360237, 3], ['Jean Luc et Catherine Blondel<br /> <a href="http://www.google.com/">GOOGLE</a>', 48.606369, 2.886894, 2]];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom : 6,
          center : new google.maps.LatLng(48.4, 1.6),
          mapTypeControl : true,
          mapTypeControlOptions : {
            style : google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
          },
          navigationControl : true,
          navigationControlOptions : {
            style : google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL,
            position : google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
          },
          scaleControl : true,
          streetViewControl : false,
          mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;

        for ( i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          /*var pictureLabel = document.createElement("img");
           pictureLabel.src = "home.jpg";*/
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map : map,
            idx : i,
            location : locations[i]
            /*title    : "CRIAQ",
             icon     : "disk.png"*/
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', onMarker_mouseOver);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', onMarker_mouseOut);
        }
      }
      function onMarker_mouseOver() {
        var marker = this;
        console.log();
        infowindow.setContent(marker.get("location")[0]);
        infowindow.open(marker.getMap(), marker);
      }
      function onMarker_mouseOut() {
        infowindow.close();
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add onmouseover to your infowindow and call the same code that made it appear in the first instance or call another function that keep your div visible. This works if you info window touch your marker

```
function onMarker_mouseOut() {
        infowindow.close();
      }
```

Remove this `infowindow.close();`

and call it an when you want on another event

Comment: is that you have a solution for this